# Reactor test Step Verifier - check that every next event matches predicate

Tags: kotlin, project-reactor

I would like to verify that every onNext emission matches the given predicate.

I tried `expectNextMatches`:

```kotlin
StepVerifier.create(...)
    .expectNextMatches { it.status != "SUCCESS" }
    .expectComplete()
    .verify()
```

However, it matches only one emission, not every single one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an operator for that:

```
StepVerifier.create(...)
    .thenConsumeWhile(it -> it.status != "SUCCESS")
    .expectComplete()
    .verify();
```

If there is any element in the sequence that doesn't match, the `StepVerifier` will error.

Comment: Minor thing: you can replace `expectComplete()` and `verify()` with simply `verifyComplete()` ;)